# Ambiguity in sonar when parsing .h files incase both c++ (community) and objectivec plugin are deployed

Tags: sonarqube

Recently we had a requirement to get static violation's for objective C language.We deployed the sonar-objective-c-plugin-0.4.0 plugin and generated a sample oclint xml with all the violation's.Now while trying to upload that xml we are encountering below error :

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 26.149s
INFO: Final Memory: 26M/1357M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
Language of file 'hybrid/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVUIWebViewNavigationDelegate.h' can not be decided as the file matches patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.c++ : **/*.cxx,**/*.cpp,**/*.cc,**/*.c,**/*.hxx,**/*.hpp,**/*.hh,**/*.h and sonar.lang.patterns.objc : **/*.h,**/*.m
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
bash-4.1$
```

Note : Since we want multi language analysis to happen we are not setting sonar.language property.

Please guide how to cater this need ?
Is there a way to disable / enable these plugin's during analysis ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer ed below page :
http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/4.5/apidocs/src-html/org/sonar/api/CoreProperties.html

and utilized the following property : sonar.excludePlugins

Comment: so what exactly has to be entered ?

Comment: In  my case I added below property in sonar-project.properties
sonar.excludePlugins=objectivec